# how to access react 360 with browser url

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to find a way, to access the react 360 with browser URL if possible

I have created a project using the react-360 package and I want to access it in app of other origin using iframe.

```
<iframe src="http://localhost:8081/index.html"></iframe>
```

On localhost:8081, project created with react-360 is running, 
  I want to access that screen using Iframe on a project running on other 
  port e.g.:-"8085", and create something like below id = "id of image or other data related to image"

```
 <iframe src="http://localhost:8081/index.html/:id"></iframe>
```

So anytime I hit with different id I see different image

something like react-router-vr package but in that I want to send the id or image name using URL so internally I can change the image using that id, something like "/test/:id", can please someone help me with that, thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. What iframe are you talking about? Can you show your code (Or create a https://codesandbox.io/)?

Comment: Hello @MoshFeu please see the edited query

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, the iframe is not relevant. You just want to show an image based on the `:id` param. Right?

Comment: Yes, I just want to show image based on id, I want to change the image of which I have sent the id and show that 360 image using iframe html tag on another project.

Comment: I made a small demo for you that present an image based on the URL (when you click on the links, notice the changes in the URL). You can also change the URL manually (which is similar to change the iframe's URL) and see that the right image is visible. Your next step will be to (1) use react-360 instead of regular image (2) put it in iframe..

Comment: Hello @MoshFeu, it will be so much helpful for me, can you please share the repository link of the demo code

Comment: Forgot to add the link: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-url-parameters-y7lkx